# Python: Comparing values in one array and replacing that value in another array at the same index from the first array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I’m trying to take user input and compare that input to the values in array B. Should the user input match one of those values in array B, I capture the index it is at and replace array A with the user input at the same index it found it in array B.

In the code example if I enter 11 it finds 11 in array B and inserts it into the same index point in array A.  But if I choose 22, 33, or 44 it does not replace anything.

What do you see wrong with the code below? Why does it recognize number 11 in array B and replaces it with 1 in array A, but not the others?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [11,22,33,44]
c = input("Enter a Number: ")

for i in b:
    if c == i:
        x = b.index(i)
        a.pop(x)
        a.insert(x,c)
        break
    else:
        print "Not in list b"
        break

print a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [11,22,33,44]
c = input("Enter a Number: ")

for i in b:
    if c == i:
        x = b.index(i)
        print x
        a.pop(x)
        a.insert(x,c)
        break
else:
    print "Not in list b"

print a
```

Putting the `else` statement outside of the `for` loop should make it work as expected. As it was, the loop would, 100% of the time, `break` after 1 iteration.